# How to close OneNote window using C#?

Tags: c#, onenote

**How to close a OneNote window opened when creating a new Page using C#?**

I downloaded Matthias' GetOCR C# project (from: [link](http://www.journeyofcode.com/free-easy-ocr-c-using-onenote/)). However, when executing the GetOCR code the OneNote windows opens and is left open even once the method finishes executing.

I know that probably one way to close this windows is sending a WM_CLOSE using the WindowHandle below:

```
app.Windows.CurrentWindow
```

However, I would like to know if there is a "nicer" way (natively supported by OneNote API) of closing the OneNote window. I can't seem to find any guidance on the OneNote API pages ([link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff925947(v=office.14).aspx)).

Comment: try sending WM_CLOSE to the WindowHandle

Comment: Thanks. However, @pushpraj please read my question - I precisely stated that I don't want to send a WM_CLOSE message. I am looking for a natively supported method to close the window using OneNote API.

Answer (score 0):

This should work unless you aren't trying to terminate the process.

```
Process[] p = Process.GetProcessesByName("onenote");
p[0].Kill();
```

I'm not sure about the process name though.

Comment: Thanks @DarkDragon, this will however simply close the first open OneNote process and not for certain the one opened due to the application. I will clarify in my question that I am looking for an approach "natively" supported to close the OneNote application.

Comment: I found these 3 lines at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh377180%28v=office.14%29.aspx though they're in VB.
although, the C# method might be similar.
    MsgBox "Closing notebook " & noteBookName, vbInformation, "Closing"
    ' Close the selected notebook.
    oneNote.CloseNotebook notebookID, False

Comment: Tried it - unfortunately this closes the current Notebook and not the OneNote window as of such i.e. similarly as you would close an Excel workbook within an Excel application window. With Excel it's more simple as it has an app.Quit function and OneNote does not.

Comment: I don't think there's any native way to close it unless it has a method to look up open sessions. More like the GetProcessesById.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is an old question, but I recently needed the ability to close the OneNote Win32 application as part of an office automation.

It is clearly possible to open a single section of a OneNote (one tab = a file with extension `.one`) using OneNote interop:

```
string sectionID = String.Empty;
var oneNoteApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.OneNote.Application();
oneNoteApp.OpenHierarchy(inputFile, null, out sectionID, CreateFileType.cftNone);
oneNoteApp.SyncHierarcy(sectionID);
oneNoteApp.NavigateTo(sectionID);
oneNoteApp.Publish(sectionID, outputFile, PublishFormat.pfPDF);
```

However, closing the section is not possible, even when obtaining the ID of the notebook.

Sending `WM_CLOSE` to the windows handle of the `oneNoteApp` (as @pushpraj suggested) will work the first few times, but after the 2nd or 3rd close, OneNote will complain that the app was not close properly. The "kill" approach (as @DarkDragon suggested) will also lead to the same issue.

The following `close` method was the only workaround I was able to find. It solved my problem.

```
var hWnd = oneNoteApp.Windows.CurrentWindows.WindowsHandle;
var phWnd = GetParent((IntPtr) hWnd);
var gphWnd = GetParent((IntPtr) phWnd);
PostMessage((IntPtr) gphWnd, WM_CLOSE, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
```

(Where `GetParent` and `PostMessage` both are available in `user32.dll`.)